# Remove duplicate rows in a diskframe object

Tags: r, duplicates, disk.frame

I have a diskframe object with many duplicate rows.
How could I remove them?
(The original dataframe is 10 Gb size)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in base R:

```
#this removes duplicate rows across the entire data frame:
df[!duplicated(df), ]

#Or if you want to remove duplicate rows at specific column(s): 
df[!duplicated(df[c('ColumnX')]), ]
```

If you want to do it using `dplyr`, then similarly either across the entire data frame or at a specific column:

```
df %>% distinct(.keep_all = TRUE)

#Or: 
df %>% distinct(ColumnX, .keep_all = TRUE)
```